# NGINX configuration for Rails 5 ActionCable with puma

Tags: nginx, jelastic, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I am using Jelastic for my development environment (not yet in production).
My application is running with Unicorn but I discovered websockets with ActionCable and integrated it in my application.

Everything is working fine in local, but when deploying to my Jelastic environment (with the default NGINX/Unicorn configuration), I am getting this message in my javascript console and I see nothing in my access log

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://dev.myapp.com:8080/' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

I used to have on my local environment and I solved it by adding the needed ActionCable.server.config.allowed_request_origins in my config file. So I double-checked my development config for this and it is ok.

That's why I was wondering if there is something specific for NGINX config, else than what is explained on ActionCable git page

```
bundle exec puma -p 28080 cable/config.ru
```

For my application, I followed everything from [enter link description here](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actioncable) but nothing's mentioned about NGINX configuration

I know that websocket with ActionCable is quite new but I hope someone would be able to give me a lead on that

Many thanks

Comment: I'm trying to solve my own problem related to this, but my Rails 5 ActionCable set up also required the `config/redis/cable.yml` to be setup such that the production url was set to something other than the default localhost line.  I'm using Heroku for production, and since ActionCable uses Redis, I added the Heroku-Redis addon to my application and used `ENV['REDIS_URL']` from my Heroku environment variables.  I read through your question and figured I'd mention what else I had to do beyond what you've tried.  Caveat: production only works with 2 devices out of all the ones of tested with :(

Comment: I have just figured my issue but it took me so much time. And I encountered many issues (I will answer to my question tomorrow). I was needing the config/redis/cable.yml too but I didn't know how to set my password in it (I have just found). 
I have read it was not easy to configure with Heroku so good luck ;)

Comment: Thanks :)  It works for two devices total.  Beyond that, nobody can connect to the cable.  Once I have it figured out, I'm going to write a blog post I think.  Once Rails 5 is out, lots of people will be trying it with Heroku

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ok so I finally managed to fix my issue. Here are the different steps which allowed to make this work:

1.nginx : I don't really know if this is needed but as my application is running with Unicorn, I added this into my nginx conf

```
upstream websocket {
  server 127.0.0.1:28080;
}

server {
  location /cable/ {
    proxy_pass http://websocket/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  }
}
```

And then in my `config/environments/development.rb` file:

```
config.action_cable.url = "ws://my.app.com/cable/"
```

2.Allowed request origin: I have then noticed that my connection was refused even if I was using `ActionCable.server.config.allowed_request_origins` in my `config/environments/development.rb` file. I am wondering if this is not due to the development default as http://localhost:3000 as stated in the documentation. So I have added this:

```
ActionCable.server.config.disable_request_forgery_protection = true
```

I have not yet a production environment so I am not yet able to test how it will be.

3.Redis password: as stated in the documentation, I was using a `config/redis/cable.yml` but I was having this error:

```
Error raised inside the event loop: Replies out of sync: #<RuntimeError: ERR operation not permitted>
/var/www/webroot/ROOT/public/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/em-hiredis-0.3.0/lib/em-hiredis/base_client.rb:130:in `block in connect'
```

So I understood the way I was setting my password for my redis server was not good.

In fact your have to do something like this:

```
development:
  <<: *local
  :url: redis://user:password@my.redis.com:6379
  :host: my.redis.com
  :port: 6379
```

And now everything is working fine and Actioncable is really impressive.

Maybe some of my issues were trivial but I am sharing them and how I resolved them so everyone can pick something if needed

Comment: you could change: ```ActionCable.server.config.disable_request_forgery_protection = true``` to ```ActionCable.server.config.allowed_request_origins = %w( ws://my.app.com/  )```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried something similar with my local environment and it was working. But deploying to my dev environment, and putting the dev url, it didn't work. 
By the way I think you are wrong with your protocol as it should be http:// and not ws:// ?

Comment: Yes I was wrong and currently I am trying to get the same thing to work.  I have three environments: -localdev, development (remote) server, production (remote) server and it works fine on localdev however I had to fallback and use ```ActionCable.server.config.disable_request_forgery_protection = true``` on the dev server as I cannot figure out yet why my suggestion to use allowed_request_origins is not working yet.

Comment: I am pretty sure they are forcing ActionCable.server.config.allowed_request_origins to http://localhost:3000 when environment is development (as written in their documentation).

Comment: New latest version of rails has its cable conf in `config/cable.yml` not `config/redis/cable.yml`.

Comment: Hi,  @phyzalis  finally are you running action cable server on Puma or Unicorn? Because the heading still says puma.

Comment: On Puma for actioncable but my application run on Unicorn

Comment: I get the following when I add your code to `nginx.config` ... `"upstream" directive is not allowed here in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:118` now just to confirm, I am adding it to `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.config` on my mac

Comment: I also get `/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:303:in `block in visit_Psych_Nodes_Alias': Unknown alias: local (Psych::BadAlias)` when I add `<<: *local` to `cable.yml`

Comment: If your mac is only for development, I think you don't need the nginx config. Nginx config is only for your production (or staging server) as I suppose you are using webrick on your mac

By the way I am sorry but I am not good enough with nginx conf to help you more

Comment: If you're using the same host to run your actioncable, it's easiest to use config.action_cable.url = "/cable"